# How do I identify Microsoft Surface traffic within Google Analytics?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8, google-analytics, touch

Is there a specific agent string I should be looking for? 
Will it only show up as "Windows 8" OS?
Is IE10 the only browser available on Surface (tablets)?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this MS doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For Surface RT, the typical agent string is

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; ARM; Trident/6.0; Touch)

For Surface Pro:

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; Touch)

There are other possible agent strings.

I think it's only possible to identify Surface RT in this way, because there is an identifier "ARM". Surface Pro runs the normal Windows 8, so you don't know whether it is a Surface Pro or some touchscreen laptop.

Comment: Great, thank you! Follow up: so there is no way to identify within Google Analytics? (I will research if I can filter by agent strings...)

Comment: @Kgosser Hmm, actually I'm not very familiar with Google Analytics, but since browsers usually don't send identification info other than agent strings, filtering these strings seems to be the only way.